# (Spring jpa) how do I get an instance from delete method

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I need to use an instance of deleted object later, but by default this deleteById method returns null. so yeah I could use findBy__ get instance of it before I delete, but I want to know  is there anyway that more simple than this?

```
val instance = repository
      .deleteById(_targetId)
      .block()!!
// I need to use this instance later
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html?is-external=true) and code a little bit. I did not find a nice solution with one method call to the repository, because any `delete` method do not return a type. I created some `remove` methods in the repository but I can not add this method to the repository with another return type. I guess there only exists the way you described. You can achieve this with the following code in a service:

```java
public Entity delete(Integer id) {
    Entity entity = repository.findById(id).orElseThrow(
                () -> new IllegalArgumentException("entity with id " + id + " does not exist"));
    repository.delete(entity);
    return entity;
}
```